# how to activate the thumb of slider to work as a button?

Tags: iphone, uislider

I want to make the thumb of my slider to work as the button so that when a user done selecting the value and pull his finger up it should do something i want.

Is there any way to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Slider Options]

Hi, 
Create this function
- (IBAction)mySliderUserFinshed:(UISlider *)theSlider

Make sure you add it to the header of you file.

The in interface builder, right click on the slider you want to act as a button.
You will need to wire up the Sent Event

Touch Up Inside to the function that you created.  If you dont know how to use interface builder watch a few quick videos on youtube or in Xcode 4 there is a short guide on some of the new and awesome features of xCode 4 with very very cool videos (takes about 10mins to watch and will save you hours of coding).

Good Luck, John.